# Coffeescript - Reduce lines of code for presence and non-same?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In Coffeescript, can these `if` and `unless` statements become a single line of code?

```
# ensure both variables are present
if var1 and var2
    # ensure the variables are different
    unless var1 is var2
        # now do something!
```

I need both variables to be present and both to be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the complement of `a is b` in the first `if`, Javascript will start evaluating the expressions from the left (short circuiting), it won't test `a isnt b` unless they are both defined

```
# Your example boils down to this
if a and b and a isnt b
     # Do something

# Why not Use a? to check if a is defined
if a? and b? and a isnt b
     # Do something
```

Comment: You don't even need the parenthesis :-)

Comment: Legendary, worked perfect. I didn't you can short circuit a statement, from left to right.